How can one "encode" momentum into the wave-equation of a QM harmonic oscillator?
I am learning about Quantum Mechanics using Griffiths book and after reading the section about the quantum harmonic oscillator, I was left wondering how one can construct a solution to the Schrodinger equation with an initial particle location probability density $p(x)$ and non-zero momentum.
For example, for a free particle, one could define the following initial wave-function at time $t=0$:
$$ \Psi(x,0)=\sqrt{p(x)}e^{-i k_0 x} $$
Therefore, one has $|\Psi(x,0)|^2=p(x)$ and this results in the following wave function as desired and for $t>0$:
$$ \Psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int \phi(k) e^{i(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t)} dk$$
where $\phi(k)$ is the Fourier-Transform of $\Psi(x,0)$. Introducing the $e^{-i k_0 x}$ factor in $\Psi(x,0)$ essentially causes a shift in the frequency of the Fourier transform such that $\phi(k)=\hat{p}(k-k_0)$ where $\hat{p}$ is the Fourier transform of $\sqrt{p(x)}$. This shift causes the momentum probability density $|\phi(k)|^2(p)$ to generate a positive expected momentum value.
Is there a similar method to generate a solution with initial probability density and non-zero momentum for the QM harmonic oscillator?
I can generate the following solution to the QM oscillator:
$$ \Psi(x,t)=\sum_n \lambda_n \psi_n(x)e^{-i\frac{E_n t}{\hbar}} $$
with $\psi_n(x)$ being the eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian operator and with $\lambda_n$ given by:
$$ \lambda_n = \langle p|\psi_n \rangle $$
However, this solution does have zero momentum. How can I generate a solution with non-zero momentum?
Solution
After thinking about the answers that were given in the comments, I now see as to how the initial condition term $\Psi(x,0)=\sqrt{p(x)}e^{-ik_0 x}$ can imprint a momentum. With the given initial wave function, the solution to the SE becomes
$$ \sum_n \psi_n(x)e^{-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar} t} $$
Expressing the summands using the Fourier transforms gives
$$ \sum_n \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi_n(k) e^{ikx} dk \right) e^{-i\frac{E_n}{\hbar} t} $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \sum_n  \phi_n(k) \right) e^{i(kx-\frac{E_n}{\hbar}t)}dk $$
from the last expression it is clear that multiplication with $e^{ipx}$ would cause a net momentum.

If you multiply a position-space wave packet $\psi(x)$ (that's real for all values of $x$), then you can imprint an average momentum $p_0$ by multiplying by $e^{ip_0x}$. See here. This works always works.

Hello and thanks for your reply. I think the issue is that in the case of the QM oscillator, I don't see how, multiplying with $e^{ip_0 x}$ results in net momentum. For the free particle the solution is a superposition of plane waves $\phi(k) e^{i(p_0 x-\omega t)}dk$, so I can see where the momentum is coming from from the de Broglie relation. In the harmonic oscillator case, I would get $\lambda_n \psi_n(x)e^{i(p_0 x -\omega t)}$. However, the latter term is not a plane wave, so how can I tell how much momentum it has?

I'm not quite sure what you are referring to, the first equation should represent a valid initial condition for the SE whereas the second equation should represent a valid solution to the $V=0$ SE if I am not mistaken?

Yes, you're right. Sorry, I now see you are just saying that this $\sqrt{p(x)}e^{ik_0x}$ is the initial wave function.

@Mantabit Every $\psi_n(x)$ (eigenstate of the SHO) has non-zero momentum in the sense that the Fourier transform $\tilde{\psi}_n(p)$ is spread out in momentum space, but the average $p$ is zero in the state $\psi_n(x)$. However, $e^{ip_0x}$ is the operator that translates by $p_0$ in momentum space, and so the state $e^{ip_0x}\psi_n(x)$ has the same momentum distribution as $\psi_n(x)$ except shifted to be centered at $p_0$, i.e., it's $\tilde{\psi}_n(p-p_0)$; hence the average momentum is $p_0$. This is all otherwise known as the shift theorem (or shift property) of Fourier transforms.
